# How to detect hash changes in WKWebView?

Tags: swift, macos, hash, wkwebview

I have a website that uses javascript that uses angular to control what you see on the website. So http://somewebsite.com/#page1 is shown and when you click on a tab that location changes to http://somewebsite.com/#page2. There will be no actual reload on the website and therefor `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` will not get triggered. How can you catch these hash changes?

Clearly Apple can, since the Safari webbrowser is able to show these changes in the location bar.

---

*Update 19.33:*

I did some research. Using `window.onhashchange` in the Safari browser this will get fired however in the WKWebView it does not. Diving deeper I use the following javascript to return the document location href every second.

```
window.setInterval(function(){ alert(document.location) }, 1000);
```

When reading that alert in WKWebView it never shows that the location changes, while in Safari you see http://somewebsite.com/#page1 and http://somewebsite.com/#page2. It seems like WKWebView does not support this feature which is extremely annoying.

Comment: did you get the solution for this?`I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 4):

No need to inject any JS. I used `webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL", options: .new, context: nil)` and this was detecting any URL changes, including hash changes. Then:

```
override func observeValue(
    forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
    of object: Any?,
    change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?,
    context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
  if object as AnyObject? === webView && keyPath == "URL" {
    onURLChange(webView.url) // onURLChange does whatever you want
  }
}
```

Don't forget to `webView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL")` in `deinit` block though.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you—this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
let script = WKUserScript(source: "(function() { \"use strict\"; addEventListener(\"hashchange\", function(event) { webkit.messageHandlers.hashchangeMessageHandler.postMessage(null); }); }) ();", injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)

let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "hashchangeMessageHandler")
configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(script)

self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: configuration)
```

Now you can fetch the hash changed URL with:

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    print("Received message: \(message.name): \(message.body)")
    print(self.webView.url)

}
```